# How to store and retrieve data from temp table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL-SQL. Please can someone help me on wrapping the below.

I need to:

- Copy contents of table A and store in global temp table
- Do an update on Table A & other tasks
- Revert contents of Table A from global temp table
- Delete temp table

ANy help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose this is some sort of assignment? Otherwise I can't see the point of doing all this.

Comment: When you say 'delete (global) temp table', do you mean delete the data? If so, you don't have to.  Part of the design/function/intent of GTT is that the data only remains for the session.  On the other hand, if you really mean 'drop' the table, then no, there is no reason to drop a GTT at all.  Again, that's part of the design/purpose.  You define them once. Then every session that uses it gets their own "copy/version" of it, and that lasts - again - only for the life of the session. But I agree with @WilliamRobertson - except as an exercise in techniques, there is no point.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table test as select * from dept;

Table created.

SQL> create global temporary table gtt_test as
  2  select * from test where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> select * from test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
         1 Dept 1         NY
         2 Dept 2         London

6 rows selected.

SQL> select * from gtt_test;

no rows selected
```

Anonymous PL/SQL block which does what you asked:

```
SQL> begin
  2    -- copy contents ...
  3    insert into gtt_test select * from test;
  4
  5    -- update A
  6    update test set loc = 'blabla';
  7    delete from test where deptno = 20;
  8
  9    -- revert
 10    delete from test;
 11    insert into test select * from gtt_test;
 12
 13    -- delete temp
 14    delete from gtt_test;
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

At the end, no changes whatsoever:

```
SQL> select * from test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
         1 Dept 1         NY
         2 Dept 2         London

6 rows selected.

SQL> select * from gtt_test;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Query you posted as a comment isn't correct; dynamic SQL must be enclosed into single quotes, it must not be terminated by a semi-colon while all other statements must. Fixed, it should be

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'create table camel_route_temp as '
                    || ' select * from acquire.CAMEL_ROUTE_PROCESS';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Temp table created');

   --update A
   UPDATE acquire.camel_route_process
      SET acquire = 'DISABLED',
          assure = 'DISABLED',
          validation = 'DISABLED',
          report = 'DISABLED',
          notification = 'DISABLED';

   COMMIT;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Aquire components disabled');
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi, Appreciate it, Have a minor issue that the production table cannot be deleted or truncated but the status column needs to be updated based on row_id from the tmp table. Please advise

Comment: I can't. I don't have your tables, while mine doesn't have columns you mentioned. What you would do is to use the UPDATE (or MERGE) statement.

Comment: I fixed code you posted and put it to the end of my answer so that it is easier to read.

Comment: <code> Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:  <code>  <code>DECLARE
BEGIN    
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create table camel_route_temp as select * from acquire.CAMEL_ROUTE_PROCESS;
    Dbms_output.put_line('Temp table created');
    -- update A
    UPDATE acquire.camel_route_process SET acquire = 'DISABLED', assure = 'DISABLED', validation = 'DISABLED', report = 'DISABLED', notification = 'DISABLED'
    commit;
    Dbms_output.put_line('Aquire components disabled');
 END;
/ <code>

Comment: There's nothing I'd like to add to what I've previously said.

Comment: Thank so much for fixing the code. @littlefoot